# Is it possible to import EPS files with iTextSharp?

Tags: itext, c#-2.0

I have to import an eps file :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("foo.eps", FileMode.Open);
iTextSharp.text.Image img = Image.GetInstance(fs);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I checked you couldn't use an EPS with iTextSharp but you can use a vector-based WMF file.